# List bash "bind -x" bindings

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I searched `man bash`, but couldn't find anything that lists out all current `bind -x` key bindings. Is there any way I could do that? I tried the following:

```
$ bind -x '"\C-`":"echo hello"'
# test binding: press CTRL+`
hello
# Binding works!
$ bind -p | grep 'hello'
# no output
$ bind -S
# no output
```

So, is there any way I could see a list of all `bind -x` currently active?

Answer (score 18):

The above answer returned empty output on bash `4.3.48` for me. But capital ‘P’ does work:

## bind - display all function names (and bindings)

This will only give you bindings to functions:

```
bind -P
```

Explanation

```
          -P     List current readline function names and bindings.
          -p     Display  readline  function  names and bindings in such a
                 way that they can be re-read.
```

Sample output

```
set-mark can be found on "\C-@", "\e ".
shell-expand-line can be found on "\e\C-e".
start-kbd-macro can be found on "\C-x(".
tilde-expand can be found on "\e&".
transpose-chars can be found on "\C-t".
transpose-words can be found on "\et".
undo can be found on "\C-x\C-u", "\C-_".
unix-line-discard can be found on "\C-u".
unix-word-rubout can be found on "\C-w".
upcase-word can be found on "\eu".
yank can be found on "\C-y".
yank-last-arg can be found on "\e.", "\e_".
yank-nth-arg can be found on "\e\C-y".
yank-pop can be found on "\ey".
```

## bind - display all string insertions

This will give you bindings for arbitrary keystrokes:

```
bind -S
```

```
      -S                 List key sequences that invoke macros and their values
      -s                 List key sequences that invoke macros and their values
                         in a form that can be reused as input.
```

sample output:

```
\el outputs ls -lrtha --color=always\C-j
\ep outputs pwd\C-j
\er outputs docker rm
\ew outputs wget --no-check-certificate \"\"\e[D
```

## manpage

Since it's surprisingly difficult to find the manpage for it, here it is:

```
bind [-m keymap] [-lpsvPSVX]
       bind [-m keymap] [-q function] [-u function] [-r keyseq]
       bind [-m keymap] -f filename
       bind [-m keymap] -x keyseq:shell-command
       bind [-m keymap] keyseq:function-name
       bind readline-command
              Display current readline key and function bindings, bind  a  key
              sequence  to  a  readline  function  or macro, or set a readline
              variable.  Each non-option argument is a  command  as  it  would
              appear  in  .inputrc, but each binding or command must be passed
              as a separate argument; e.g.,  '"\C-x\C-r":  re-read-init-file'.
              Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
              -m keymap
                     Use keymap as the keymap to be affected by the subsequent
                     bindings.    Acceptable   keymap   names    are    emacs,
                     emacs-standard,   emacs-meta,  emacs-ctlx,  vi,  vi-move,
                     vi-command,  and  vi-insert.    vi   is   equivalent   to
                     vi-command; emacs is equivalent to emacs-standard.
              -l     List the names of all readline functions.
              -p     Display  readline  function  names and bindings in such a
                     way that they can be re-read.
              -P     List current readline function names and bindings.
              -s     Display readline key sequences bound to  macros  and  the
                     strings  they  output  in such a way that they can be re-
                     read.
              -S     Display readline key sequences bound to  macros  and  the
                     strings they output.
              -v     Display  readline variable names and values in such a way
                     that they can be re-read.
              -V     List current readline variable names and values.
              -f filename
                     Read key bindings from filename.
              -q function
                     Query about which keys invoke the named function.
              -u function
                     Unbind all keys bound to the named function.
              -r keyseq
                     Remove any current binding for keyseq.
              -x keyseq:shell-command
                     Cause shell-command to be  executed  whenever  keyseq  is
                     entered.   When shell-command is executed, the shell sets
                     the  READLINE_LINE  variable  to  the  contents  of   the
                     readline  line  buffer and the READLINE_POINT variable to
                     the current location of  the  insertion  point.   If  the
                     executed  command  changes  the value of READLINE_LINE or
                     READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the
                     editing state.
              -X     List  all  key  sequences bound to shell commands and the
                     associated commands in a format that  can  be  reused  as
                     input.

              The  return value is 0 unless an unrecognized option is given or
              an error occurred.
```

Comment: What command should I use to view the man page? Whenever I run `man bind` it shows me the manpage for binding a name to a socket

Comment: I was only able to reach this info via we web-based man page. From the command line I vague;u recall this info was difficult to find.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: Probably not. But it was too long ago for me to find out :)

Comment: `bind` is not a standalone program, it is a bash builtin. Use `help bind` to get it's help (also works for other builtins like `if` or `cd`).

Comment: `bind -p` or `bind -P` have nothing to do with `bind -x`.

Comment: I think the manage output I gave speaks for itself regarding what each option does. Feel free to edit the answer if I've stated something incorrect

Answer (score 13):

Seems like you can use `bind -X` (new in Bash **4.3**):

```
$ help bind
      ...
      -x  keyseq:shell-command  Cause SHELL-COMMAND to be executed when
                                KEYSEQ is entered.
      -X                        List key sequences bound with -x and
                                associated commands in a form that can be
                                reused as input.
      ...
$
```

Comment: I don't know which version of bash you are using, but for me `bind -X` returns `invalid option`. Indeed, `help bind` does not list `-X` for me. On my machine, `bash --version` produces `version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I'm using 4.3 (beta). I did not know it's a new added feature. :)

Comment: Huh! So, I guess I'll just hang tight then :-P 

Do you know their release schedule/workaround for 4.2?

Comment: No idea about the exact schedule.

Comment: @Savui: Bash 4.3 was just released two weeks ago.

Comment: Arrrgh, the servers at my workplace are on `4.2.25`.