# Bind "up arrow" key to fzf command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, fzf

I want to use the `fzf` fuzzyfinder command history instead of the typical command history when I press the up arrow.

In my fzf shell keybindings file I'm able to edit which key brings up the fuzzy finder by editing the following snippet:

`bindkey '{command such as ^R}' fzf-history-widget`

How can I represent the `up arrow` key so that it calls this function when pressed? Do I have to disable other functionality somewhere else as well?

Comment: thanks for question, I'll try that keybinding for myself too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Binding `<Up>` key in `zsh`

Use

```sh
bindkey "${key[Up]}" fzf-history-widget
```

or

```
bindkey '^[[A' fzf-history-widget
```

or

```
bindkey "${terminfo[kcuu1]}" up-line-or-history
```

to bind `<Up>` key in `zsh` to `fzf-history-widget` function.

## Binding `<Up>` key in `bash`

You can set the `<Up>` arrow key to show the commands from history beginning with the characters before the cursor on the command line

```sh
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
```

### `fzf` bindings for `bash`

There is an [issue #1492:
[bash] Fire command directly with CTRL-X in CTRL-R](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/pull/1492)

Accordingly, [history-exec.bash](https://github.com/4z3/fzf-plugins#history-execbash) plugin created for the purpose of history expansion using `fzf`

### macOS Specific Binding

`bindkey "${terminfo[kcuu1]}" fzf-history-widget`

Comment: That's throwing the error: `cannot bind to an empty key sequence` where a valid setting is `bindkey "^R" fzf-history-widget` (I am working in `zsh`)

Comment: Which version of `zsh` do you use? It works for me ( `zsh --version` :
`zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)` )

Comment: I'm `zsh 5.7.1 (on macOS)`

Comment: Try `bindkey '^[[A'  fzf-history-widget` or `bindkey "${terminfo[kcuu1]}" up-line-or-history`

Comment: No luck there either

Comment: Sorry. Anyway, thanks for your idea to use Up arrow

Comment: Actually, briefly got into a state where it worked. Trying to reproduce and then I'll make a not on the answer, but upvoting for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[**In bash** version 4 or more](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/f799b568d1a5644188b6edaeec3df5167b3e2268/shell/key-bindings.bash#L79-L89), **none of [these](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/f799b568d1a5644188b6edaeec3df5167b3e2268/shell/key-bindings.bash#L86-L88)** works for me:

```sh
bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-p": __fzf_history__'
bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-p": __fzf_history__'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-p": __fzf_history__'
```

This **also doesn't work**:

```sh
bind '"\C-p": __fzf_history__'
```

But **this one does** the trick for me:

```sh
bind -x '"\C-p": __fzf_history__'
```

By the way, you can use [`bind -X`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761888/9157799) to see the current binding.